# Android: How can I multiply a class and create different instances of its variables?

Tags: java, android, class

I'm new to Java, so I hope it's not a silly question. I have a class called "Enemy".

I know how to multiply the class, I use the "for" loop. Now, the problem is that the variables x and y (the one's that move the bitmap) have the same values for every instance of the class. And I want them to be different in order to create some "randomness".

The main class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{


    Player ourView; 

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility") protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        ourView = new Player(this);

        setContentView(ourView);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ourView.pause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ourView.resume();
    }


}
```

Here's the "Player" class:

```
public class Player extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    boolean isRunning = true;

    public Player(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        isRunning = false;
        while(true){
        try{
            ourThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    ourThread = null;
}

    public void resume() {
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(isRunning) {
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

                canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawRGB(30, 30, 200);

                Enemy[] enemy = new Enemy[3];
                for(int i = 0; i<enemy.length; i++){
                    enemy[i] = new Enemy(null);
                    enemy[i].draw();
                }

            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }           
    }
}
```

And here's the "Enemy" class:

```
public class Enemy extends Player{

    public Enemy(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    float x,y = (float) (Math.random()*200);

    public void draw(){
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);

    }
}
```

I've also tried to declare those variables inside the "Enemy" class, but they just don't work. The bitmap stays in (0,0).

NOTE: The "Player" and "Enemy" class are declared inside the "MainActivity" class.

Comment: Every class should have its own java file ;). And if you done that, you can create a constructor for `Enemy` and fill the x and y variables there: `public Enemy() { x = (float) (Math.random()*200); y = (float) (Math.random()*200); }`. That way every instance of `Enemy` has its own coordinates.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. I've tried that, it just doesn't seem to work. The bitmap stays at the coordinates (0,0).

Comment: Can you please update your question and show use your changes?

Comment: I've just declared the "Enemy" class in another file, but the problem it's that the method "Run()" doesn't recognize the class.

Comment: Have you imported the class using an `import` statement?

Comment: Okay, now it's working. Every class in a different file, but the variables (declared inside the class) remain the same.

Comment: @Gonzalo : Are you trying to access that "Enemy" class of "MainActivity" in another activity?

Comment: No, I only have one activity in this case.

Comment: Please update you code inside your question.

Comment: I've updated the code. Every class is in a different file. I don't know why, but eclipse asked me to create a constructor, which I did. But now the app is crashing.

Comment: Why is `Enemy` extending the `Player` class? And what is the Exception message? You can find that in the logcat window in Eclipse.

Comment: It's extending Player because otherwise it wouldn't recognize "canvas", and Canvas has to be declared in Player in case I want to create other types of classes like "Enemy". There are a lot of messages, but one of them says: "Fatal exception: Thread-114"

Comment: Pass the current canvas of the `Player` class to the Enemy instance: `enemy[i] = new Enemy(canvase, context);` (don't forget to update the constructor in the Enemy classe). The most important part of the Stacktrace is the last `Caused By` part and the information where it occurs.

Comment: Have you fixed your problem?

Comment: No, I couldn't yet. Basically the problem is that when I multiply the class, all the variables inside of it adopt the same value, even thought they are set to random. I want a different value of x and y for every instance of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Enemy` class should not extend the `Player` class since they don't share any similarities except the canvas and the context.
A possible implementation of your Enemy could look like this:

```
public class Enemy {
  private Bitmap bitmap;
  private Canvas canvas;
  private Context context;
  private float x, y;

  public Enemy(Canvas canvas, Context context) {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    x = (float) (Math.random() * 200);
    y = (float) (Math.random() * 200);
  }

  public void draw() {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);
  }

  public void printCoordinates() { // just used for printing
    System.out.println("x = " + x + " / y = "+ y);
  }
}
```

Your `Player` class just need a minor adjustment to create proper `Enemy` classes:

```
Enemy[] enemy = new Enemy[3];
for(int i = 0; i < enemy.length; i++){
    enemy[i] = new Enemy(canvas, context);
    enemy[i].printCoordinates(); // just used for printing the generated coordinates
    enemy[i].draw();
}
```

You just have to provide proper `canvas` and `context` instances for the new Enemy instance. You may also drop the context instance since you (currently) don't use it anythere in that class.

This is an example print of above code:

```
x = 27.236885 / y = 7.8905525
x = 61.842735 / y = 158.4654
x = 186.16629 / y = 20.208426
```

If you really want to extend the `Player` class, then you can still do that. This won't change much in your `Enemy class`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. The only thing it's that it goes in a never ending loop. It's generating random values for each one of them but all the time. I want those values to be created and then the bitmap to stay in that place. How can I do that?

Comment: You're creating new `Enemy` instances while the `Player` thread is running, that's why you're getting more and more bitmaps on the canvas. You should think about what you really want. If you want only 3 enemies on the screen, then you should extract the "`Enemy` loop" to a separat method that will check if there are 3 instances available and create new one if necessary. You should also store the available enemy instance in a `List<Enemy>` as a variable in the `Player` class to allow access the current enemies. Use that List instead of `Enemy[]`.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks very much for taking the time.

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend an own class that will handle the available enemies. That would be much cleaner than a single method in the `Player` class :).